# Angular 5 "map is not defined"

Tags: json, rxjs, observable, angular5

I have .Net 4.6.2 VS 2017 Mvc application, with Angular 5, "rxjs": "^5.5.10"

I am trying to get data for Kendo UI grid through controller. The controller is returning data which I can see, but in the service class at code .map(response => response.json()), it says illegal return statement.(Please see attached image)
[image]

[err img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9KHt.png)

Here is vto.service.ts

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { VTO } from './vto';
    import { Http, HttpModule, Headers,  Response } from '@angular/http';
    import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };
    import {
        toDataSourceRequestString,
        translateDataSourceResultGroups,
        translateAggregateResults,
        DataResult,
        DataSourceRequestState
    } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    import { GridDataResult, DataStateChangeEvent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

    @Injectable()
    export class Vtos {


       //  private vtoUrl = location.href.replace(location.hash, '') + '/home/GetVtos';

        private vtoUrl = 'http://localhost:63213/Home/GetVtos';

        constructor(private http: Http) { }

            public getVtos(state: DataSourceRequestState): Observable<DataResult> {

            const queryStr = `${toDataSourceRequestString(state)}`; //serialize the state
            const hasGroups = state.group && state.group.length;
            return this.http
              .get(`${this.vtoUrl}?${queryStr}`) //send the state to the server
              .map(response => response.json())
              .map(({ data, total/*, aggregateResults*/ }) => // process the response
                (<GridDataResult>{
                  //if there are groups convert them to compatible format
                  data: hasGroups ? translateDataSourceResultGroups(data) : data,
                  total: total,
                  // convert the aggregates if such exists
                  //aggregateResult: translateAggregateResults(aggregateResults)
                }))
        }
    }
```

HomeController call to GetVots

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using VTO.DTO;
using VTO.DAL;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
namespace VTO.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetVtos([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return new JsonResult
            {
                ContentType = "application/json",
                Data = Vto.GetVtos().ToDataSourceResult(request),
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue
            };
        }
}
```

Comment: The error is elsewhere.  Considering that you get an exception in your code, this means that there's likely an `eval()` happening somewhere.  (If the syntax error was in your code -- at least the code you have shown us -- you wouldn't be getting this far.)

Comment: My suspicion is that controller is returning data, but in service class it is not being captured. Is there any way I can test. I apologize, I am new to angular, observables, etc.

Comment: I did a console.log(response.json) and I get- Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp../src/app/services/vto.service.ts.Vtos.getVtos (vto.service.ts:44), <anonymous>:1:13)
    at Vtos.webpackJsonp../src/app/services/vto.service.ts.Vtos.getVtos (vto.service.ts:44)
    at new VtoReportComponent (vto-report.component.ts:40)                Any thought?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations here, **this module is deprecated**. [See details here](https://angular.io/api/http/Http). **Remove it from your app.**

```
import { Http, HttpModule, Headers,  Response } from '@angular/http';
```

You should use `HttpClientModule`,

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
```

Keep it mind you have to import `HttpClientModule` on your **app.module.ts** (or any other module you have a dependency for it)

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Since `HttpClientModule` came into play. You not longer need for `response.json()`. Now `HttpClient.get()` returns an Observable of typed `HttpResponse` rather than just the JSON data. [See docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data). (**vto.service.ts**)

Remove,

```
.map(response => response.json())
```

Then you have,

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

public getVtos(state: DataSourceRequestState): Observable<DataResult> {
  ...
  return this.http
          .get(`${this.vtoUrl}?${queryStr}`)
          .map(({ data, total/*, aggregateResults*/ }) =>
            (<GridDataResult>{
              data: hasGroups ? translateDataSourceResultGroups(data) : data,
              total: total,
              translateAggregateResults(aggregateResults)
            }))
}
```

Comment: I did as you guided. In addition, constructor(private http: HttpClient). Now I get error TS2459: Type 'Object' has no property 'total' and no string index signature.Is there any way I can send you a sample app, so that you can guide better. Thanks

Comment: but this also includes asp.net MVC as well

Comment: still .map is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Sharing what worked for me. As Luillyfe mentioned Http is now deprecated, HttpClient is to be used. The returned response is already in Json, so no longer need to use .Json method.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
public getVtos(state: DataSourceRequestState): Observable<DataResult> {
    const queryStr = `${toDataSourceRequestString(state)}`; //serialize the state
    const hasGroups = state.group && state.group.length;
    return this.http
        .get(`${this.vtoUrl}?${queryStr}`) //send the state to the server
        .pipe(
        map(<DataResult>({ Data, Total/*, aggregateResults*/ }) => {// process the response
            console.log(Data);
            return (<GridDataResult>{

                data: hasGroups ? translateDataSourceResultGroups(Data) : Data.map(item => {
                    item.ReportDate = new Date(item.ReportDate); // convert to actual JavaScript date object
                    return item;
                }),
                total: Total

            })
        })
        )
}
```